# Регулярное выражение - до первого вхождения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не работает, как надо:

```
$value = preg_replace ('/<p>(.+):/', '<p><strong>\\1:</strong>', $value);
```

Необходимо все строки, которые начинаются на

```
<p>текст: ...
```

заменить на

```
<p><strong>текст:</strong> ...
```

Регулярна пропускает первый знак `:` иногда и создает `<strong>` на несколько строк.

Как сделать "от `<p>` до первого вхождения знака `:`, но если до `</p>` его нет - пропустить"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [ленивый квантификатор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.96.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B8_.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BA.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F), ваша регулярка тогда будет выглядеть так:

```
<p>(.+?):
```

Comment: Плюс. Неправильно понял задание

Comment: минус без комментариев.

Comment: И как же ваша регулярка отработает со строкой  `<p>test</p><p>:</p>` ("_от `<p>` до первого вхождения знака `:`, но если до `</p>` его нет - пропустить_")? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужна вот такая регулярка([пример на regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yrkyUi/1)):

```
/<p>([^<]+?:)/
```

А вот и рабочий пример PHP кода ([пример на 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/3YCKc)):

```
$input = [
    '<p>test:</p>',
    '<p>test: foo</p>',
    '<p>foo:</p>',
    '<p>: foo</p>',
    '<p>test </p><p>:</p>',
];

foreach ($input as $val) {
    echo(preg_replace('/(<p>)([^<]+?:)(.*)/', '$1<strong>$2</strong>$3', $val));
    echo("\n");
}
```

Вывод:

```
<p><strong>test:</strong></p>
<p><strong>test:</strong> foo</p>
<p><strong>foo:</strong></p>
<p>: foo</p>
<p>test </p><p>:</p>
```

**Замечание:**

Вместо того, чтобы пытаться разобрать HTML регулярными выражениями - используйте нормальный HTML парсер. Поверьте, это не так сложно, как кажется, но сэкономит вам кучу времени и нервов.

Answer (score 1):

> от `<p>` до первого вхождения знака `:`

Это есть в [соседнем ответе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/653606/178988):

```
<p>(.+?):
```

> но если до `</p>` его нет - пропустить

но чтобы работало так, его надо немного изменить:

```
<p>((?:(?!</p>).)+?):
```

PS: А вообще, двоеточие должно бы быть внутри группы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сменить паттерн:

Для поиска взять такой:

```
'<p>(.+):(.*)'
```

А заменять строку так:

```
'<p><strong>\\1:\\2</strong>'
```

Учитывайте, что это паттерны не для php, поэтому их, возможно надо будет переделать. На Python я провёл следующие тесты:

```
import re

values = ['<p>какой-то текст: текст после ":"', 'это не будет изменено', '<p>ещё текст: и текст после двоеточия', '<p>ещё для теста: текст справа', 'а я простая строка, и я не буду изменена']

for value in values:
    value = re.sub(r'<p>(.+):(.*)', r'<p><strong>\1:\2</strong>', value)
    print(value)
```

Вывод из этих данных такой:

`<p><strong>какой-то текст: текст после ":"</strong>`

`это не будет изменено`

`<p><strong>ещё текст: и текст после двоеточия</strong>`

`<p><strong>ещё для теста: текст справа</strong>`

`а я простая строка, и я не буду изменена`

Answer (score 0):

> Как сделать "от `<p>` до первого вхождения знака `:`, но если до `</p>` его нет - пропустить"?

Например можно использовать такое регулярное выражение для поиска подстроки для замены:

```
/<p>\K((?:[^:<]+(?:<(?!\/p>))*)+:)/
```

Пример https://regex101.com/r/PnFdjd/2

Код замены

```
$value = preg_replace ('/<p>\K((?:[^:<]+(?:<(?!\/p>))*)+:)/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $value);
```